# Typeerror when including a module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm following the nodeschool [learnyounode](https://github.com/workshopper/learnyounode) tutorial and I'm having some trouble with [the module lesson](https://github.com/workshopper/learnyounode/blob/master/exercises/make_it_modular/problem.md). In short I'm supposed to make a module which I pass a directory to and a file extension and then use a callback to print the list of files with that extension in the folder.

I have two files, my module (mymodule.js):

```
var module = require('module');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function(testDirectory, testExtension, callback)
{
    fs.readdir(testDirectory, function(error, folderContents)
    {
        if (error) return callback(error);
        for (i = 0; i < folderContents.length; i++)
        {
            var fileExtension = path.extname(folderContents[i]);
            if(fileExtension === "." + testExtension)
            {
                callback(null, folderContents[i]);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

and my app file (program.js):

```
var mymodule = require('./mymodule.js');

mymodule(process.argv[2], process.argv[3], function(error, data)
{
    console.log(data);
});
```

Whenever I try test my app file, I get *TypeError: mymodule is not a function*

I've done lots of reading, but the more I read the more confused I become. Someone please help?

Comment: remove `var module = require('module');`

Comment: I knew it was going to be something like that. Thank you Amit!